# Fatal error: Unable to find Gruntfile

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

grunt --version

```
grunt-cli v0.1.8
grunt v0.4.1
```

$ npm -v

```
1.2.18
```

$ node -v

```
v0.10.6
```

When I run `grunt init` to create the `Gruntfile.js`, I get error:

```
$ grunt init 
A valid Gruntfile could not be found. Please see the getting started guide for
more information on how to configure grunt: http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
Fatal error: Unable to find Gruntfile.
```

I have searched for Grunfile.js, and I get:

```
/home/ka/.npm/grunt-cli/0.1.8/package/Gruntfile.js
/home/ka/tmp/npm-1464/1368671910572-0.38816986070014536/package/Gruntfile.js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt/Gruntfile.js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/Gruntfile.js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/Gruntfile.js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/node_modules/findup-sync/Gruntfile.js
/ex/co/www/dev/htdocs/unittest/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/Gruntfile.js
/ex/co/www/dev/htdocs/unittest/node_modules/grunt/Gruntfile.js
/root/.npm/findup-sync/0.1.2/package/Gruntfile.js
/root/.npm/grunt/0.4.1/package/Gruntfile.js
/root/.npm/grunt-cli/0.1.8/package/Gruntfile.js
```

Can i just copy one of these grunt files, to /ex/co/www/dev/htdocs/unittest (where the Javascript / quint test are)?  Or is there something else I am missing?

I am trying to run grunt on Centos 6.4.  Also, why doesn't `grunt init` create the `Gruntfile.js`?

```
cp /root/.npm/grunt/0.4.1/package/Gruntfile.js /ex/co/www/dev/htdocs/unittest/
```

I copied it AS-IS and now I get better errors:

```
grunt 
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-jshint" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-nodeunit" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-watch" not found. Is it installed?
Warning: Task "jshint" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

mode progress....

```
grunt 
Running "jshint:gruntfile" (jshint) task
Warning: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
kahmed@vm-devqa01 /ex/co/www/dev/htdocs/unittest $ grunt --force
Running "jshint:gruntfile" (jshint) task
Warning: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined Used --force, continuing.
Warning: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined Used --force, continuing.

Running "jshint:libs_n_tests" (jshint) task
Warning: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined Used --force, continuing.
Warning: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined Used --force, continuing.

Running "jshint:subgrunt" (jshint) task
Warning: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined Used --force, continuing.
Warning: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined Used --force, continuing.

Running "nodeunit:all" (nodeunit) task
Warning: Cannot call method 'map' of undefined Used --force, continuing.
Warning: Cannot call method 'map' of undefined Used --force, continuing.

Running "subgrunt:all" (subgrunt) task
Warning: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined Used --force, continuing.
Warning: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined Used --force, continuing.

Done, but with warnings.
```

My Gruntfile.js:

```
/*
 * grunt
 * http://gruntjs.com/
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2013 "Cowboy" Ben Alman
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/LICENSE-MIT
 */

'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    nodeunit: {
      all: ['test/{grunt,tasks,util}/**/*.js']
    },
    jshint: {
      gruntfile: ['Gruntfile.js'],
      libs_n_tests: ['lib/**/*.js', '<%= nodeunit.all %>'],
      subgrunt: ['<%= subgrunt.all %>'],
      options: {
        curly: true,
        eqeqeq: true,
        immed: true,
        latedef: true,
        newcap: true,
        noarg: true,
        sub: true,
        undef: true,
        unused: true,
        boss: true,
        eqnull: true,
        node: true,
        es5: true
      }
    },
    watch: {
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['<%= jshint.gruntfile %>'],
        tasks: ['jshint:gruntfile']
      },
      libs_n_tests: {
        files: ['<%= jshint.libs_n_tests %>'],
        tasks: ['jshint:libs_n_tests', 'nodeunit']
      },
      subgrunt: {
        files: ['<%= subgrunt.all %>'],
        tasks: ['jshint:subgrunt', 'subgrunt']
      }
    },
    subgrunt: {
      all: ['test/gruntfile/*.js']
    },
  });

  // These plugins provide necessary tasks.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-nodeunit');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-qunit');

  grunt.registerTask('test', 'qunit:src');

  // "npm test" runs these tasks
  grunt.registerTask('test', ['jshint', 'nodeunit', 'subgrunt']);

  // Default task.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['test']);

  // Run sub-grunt files, because right now, testing tasks is a pain.
  grunt.registerMultiTask('subgrunt', 'Run a sub-gruntfile.', function() {
    var path = require('path');
    grunt.util.async.forEachSeries(this.filesSrc, function(gruntfile, next) {
      grunt.util.spawn({
        grunt: true,
        args: ['--gruntfile', path.resolve(gruntfile)],
      }, function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
          grunt.log.error(result.stdout).writeln();
          next(new Error('Error running sub-gruntfile "' + gruntfile + '".'));
        } else {
          grunt.verbose.ok(result.stdout);
          next();
        }
      });
    }, this.async());
  });

};
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the actual command line tool `grunt-init` found in the [Project Scaffolding](http://gruntjs.com/project-scaffolding) documentation.

Your current command `grunt init` is looking for a `Gruntfile.js` and the task `init` inside it. It is obviously unable to find your `Gruntfile.js` so is throwing that error.

#### Edit:

Your new error is because you have copied a `Gruntfile.js` file over and the `default` task (found near the bottom if you want to open it) will be calling those modules. Normally you will have used something like `bower` to install them into your local directory.

Your default task I referred to above will look something like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'qunit', 'concat', 'uglify']);
```

This is basically saying: when I run `grunt` at the command line, run the tasks `jshint`, `qunit`, `concat` and `uglify` in that order. These tasks will have been specified earlier on in the `Gruntfile`. To understand the file more check out a [sample Gruntfile](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Sample-Gruntfile).

May I suggest taking a look at the [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) as it is a great tool to provide you with scaffolding for your apps (including a working `Gruntfile.js`).

#### Edit 2:

It is important you understand what is happening. The `Gruntfile.js` you have copied over looks to be calling "subgrunt" tasks. i.e. `grunt` tasks in sub projects. Is this what you are wanting?

Following through your `Gruntfile.js` - when you run `grunt` it is calling the following order: `'jshint', 'nodeunit', 'subgrunt'`.

Ideally you want to write this yourself rather than copying it as there are some options being called by `jshint` I am unfamiliar with. If you read the [jshint documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint) it doesn't mention the first three options.

I think you should try something like this:

```
jshint: {
  options: {
    curly: true,
    eqeqeq: true,
    immed: true,
    latedef: true,
    newcap: true,
    noarg: true,
    sub: true,
    undef: true,
    unused: true,
    boss: true,
    eqnull: true,
    node: true,
    es5: true
  }
  files: {
    src: ['path/to/your/*.js', 'another/path/to/your/*.js']
  }
}
```

You should read through the documentation for each task and make sure you understand the options you are passing through.

Another hint. If you see a file reference like the following:

```
 <%= jshint.gruntfile %>
```

This is a reference to a particular file/property set in the `Gruntfile.js`. In this case, this came from the `watch` task and points to the `jshint.gruntfile` property as a file to watch.

Comment: Yes Yeoman looks promising. and i will certainly try it. I just need to finish this grunt thing, to be able to move on. I guess its my compulsive and obsessive nature :) so i am going to update the original text, as i made some progress

Comment: Excellent - yup update your question and I'll have another look at it. Did my answer make sense/help you?

Answer (score 13):

I had this same error, and it turned out I just needed to run npm install first.  Even though I had already installed npm previously, something had become corrupt w/ the installation.  A quick re-install worked; All I needed were these two commands:

```
npm install
grunt jshint
```

Comment: Thank you sir `npm install` put me out of my misery.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I used the below commands and it worked for me

```
grunt -f 
grunt server
```

Hope it works for you also.

Answer (score 0):

Grunt file should be in root directory not inside a folder somewhere, also it should spell **"Gruntfile.js"**.

**Example**

In case of asp.net Core angular project its location should be.

[image]

It wont work if you put this file inside ClientApp or somewhere else until you define some method to do this.

Answer (score -1):

check whether you are on dirctory that you are working on and
run npm install there it will probably solve your problem