# how to build ng2-material v0.8.1 example site

Tags: angular, gruntjs, angular-material, angular-cli

I want to start ng2-material [this](https://justindujardin.github.io/ng2-material/#/) site in my local machine using [this](https://github.com/justindujardin/ng2-material/tree/master/modules/site) documentation. First I created new project in local using angular-cli `ng new myProject` command.

But now I not have idea what I should do next?

Documentation says:

[image]

but when I do `grunt build-npm` command in myProject directory I got `Fatal error: Unable to find Gruntfile.` error.

---

#### Edited:

I tried:

1. Clone their repository: https://github.com/justindujardin/ng2-material.git
2. cd ./ng2-material
3. Run npm install in the root
4. Run grunt build-npm
5. cd ./modules/site
6. Run npm install
7. Run ng serve

### Step 7

First I downgraded `angular-cli` to 1.0.0.beta10 becouse `ng2-material` 0.8.1 not want work with `angular-cli` 1.0.0.beta21.

problems after `ng-serve` command (has no exported mng 'MATERIAL_DIRECTIVES'):

```
The Broccoli Plugin: [BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler] failed with:
Error: Typescript found the following errors:
  /home/user/4learn/ng2-material/modules/site/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-0tzJEdmQ.tmp/0/src/app/+components/components.component.ts (3, 9): Module '"/home/user/4learn/ng2-material/modules/site/node_modules/ng2-material/index"' has no exported mng 'MATERIAL_DIRECTIVES'
```

.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Unable to find Gruntfile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611235/fatal-error-unable-to-find-gruntfile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test the ng2-material example locally, you should use their project-source and not create a new custom project.

1. Clone their repository: git@github.com:justindujardin/ng2-material.git
2. `cd ./ng2-material`
3. Run `npm install` in the root
4. Run `grunt build-npm`
5. `cd ./modules/site`
6. Run `npm install`
7. Run `ng serve`

---

If you just want to use ng2-material in your own project, follow the instructions here: https://justindujardin.github.io/ng2-material/#/

Install the ng2-material and the material2 core libraries:

```
npm install --save ng2-material @angular2-material/core
```

Then import the material directives and providers

```
import {MATERIAL_DIRECTIVES, MATERIAL_PROVIDERS} from "ng2-material";
```

Then reference the styles in your page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/ng2-material/ng2-material.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/ng2-material/font/font.css">
```

---

If you just want to use the basic material-components, you should check out this *official* project: https://github.com/angular/material2

Comment: You answer is very helpful. Now I stick on last step. When try `ng serve` got `It seems like you're using a project generated using an old version of the Angular CLI` error.

Comment: The ng2-material project is using an older angular-cli version than what you have installed globally - you can try "npm start" - if that doesn't work you'll have to install an older version of angular-cli

Comment: After downgrade angular-cli to 1.0.0.beta10 `ng serve' start work but get new error, please look to edited post.

Comment: You should look into the pqckage.json -> it says that the angular-cli version used is "0.0.x" - so using 1.0.0 will most likely not solve your issue