# I'm trying to git commit files -- unable to find gruntfile

Tags: git, gruntjs, git-bash

I'm trying to commit changes to two staged files in my git repo.  when I execute the git commit -m"comment" command, I get the message Fatal error: "Unable to find Gruntfile."

The two files are unrelated to anything to do with using grunt.

**Question:** How can I get my git to stop checking for grunt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Unable to find Gruntfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611235/fatal-error-unable-to-find-gruntfile)

Comment: I doubt it's a dup. The question is why `git` runs `grunt` at all (a pre-commit hook, for sure) and how to stop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost certainly you have a pre-commit hook.

```
git commit --no-verify
```

allows to avoid it once. Or you can remove it completely from .git/hooks.

Comment: I have this in my pre-commit.. what should I remove?

`#!/bin/sh
# husky
cd MyDirectory/jspm_packages/npm/jquery@3.1.1
[ -f package.json ] && cat package.json | grep -q '"precommit"\s*:'
[ $? -ne 0 ] && exit 0
command -v npm >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "husky - can't find npm in PATH. Skipping precommit script in package.json"; exit 0; }
npm run precommit
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo
  echo "husky - pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)"
  echo
  exit 1
fi`  thanks @phd

Comment: That's [tag:husky] `pre-commit`. I don't know how it's configured. Perhaps file `package.json`, key `"precommit-checks"`.